# Using jQuery in ckeditor within Liferay portal

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, liferay-6

does anybody know, how to make jQuery work in ckeditor plugin ? I created a plugin and I loaded it in ckconfig.jsp

```
CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'myPlugin';
```

But the problem is that jQuery-1.4.4.min that I load from liferay-plugins.xml (or in theme for the entire portal) isn't loaded in global context when the plugin executes. I can use jquery everywhere within portal successfully, but not in ckeditor plugin. The initialization of ckeditor is kinda complex and I don't see how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ckeditor.jsp, which is included from  tag, contains the entire HTML document with  etc. So that all third party javascripts, that are available for ckeditor, are those included in ckeditor.jsp's head section.

so that it should be as follows (ckeditor.jsp):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.js"></script>
```

And jquery will be available for ckeditor plugins.